# Отдалить один угол div

Tags: css, css-animation

Знатоки, столкнулся с такой проблемой. Необходимо с помощью css отдалить д[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался делать с помощью translateZ, но как бы можем обратиться именно к нужной стороне?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы сделал через перспективу, но вот со значениями придется поиграться..

```css
*, ::after, ::before
{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


button
{
  border: none;
  background-color: #FF4800;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  
  transform: rotateY(10deg) translateX(10px);
}

.wrap
{
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  perspective : 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <button>Скидка 15%</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, а perspective не распространяется на тег span?

Comment: Я думаю может, если span будет блочным.

Answer (score 2):

Такой вариант..

```css
div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 12px;
  transform: perspective(230px) rotateY(12deg);
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", "Comic Sans", bold;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>Скидка 15%</div>
```